# Print all supported URL schemes in Java8

Tags: java, url

Is there any way to print all supported URL schemes in Java8? I know Java8 supports `http`, `https`, `file` etc. but what else is supported and will be correctly processed by `URL.openStream()` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadoc for `java.net.URL` states:

> Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist on the search path :           http, https, file, and jar
>
> Protocol handlers for additional protocols may also be available.

If you want more than **http, https, file, and jar**, you need to configure them yourself by writing and loading a Protocol Handler.

- If the application has previously set up an instance of `URLStreamHandlerFactory` as the stream handler factory, then the `createURLStreamHandler` method of that instance is called with the protocol string as an argument to create the stream protocol handler.
- If no `URLStreamHandlerFactory` has yet been set up, or if the factory's `createURLStreamHandler` method returns null, then the constructor finds the value of the system property: `java.protocol.handler.pkgs`
- If the value of that system property is not null, it is interpreted as a list of packages separated by a vertical slash character '|'. The constructor tries to load the class named `<package>.<protocol>.Handler`

....where `<package>`  is replaced by the name of the package and `<protocol>` is replaced by the name of the protocol. If this class does not exist, or if the class exists but it is not a subclass of `URLStreamHandler`, then the next package in the list is tried.

- If the previous step fails to find a protocol handler, then the constructor tries to load from a system default package : `<system default package>.<protocol>.Handler`